# Regarding performance issues after synchronization with CloudKit

Tags: cloudkit

Has anyone, during CKAsset synchronization between the device and iCloud, had a serious slowdown in application elements seemingly unrelated to iCloud? For example, is it possible that `UINavigationViewController#pushViewController` works slower than before? The only difference that I've been able to notice is that I upload objects to iCloud. If yes, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You do have to be aware that CloudKit callback code blocks are executed on a background thread. If you don't call the main thread it would look like your application is not responsive. If you have a callback and within that callback you want to access UI components, then make sure it's in a code block like:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
   ... your code ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I do it. But the problem begins after completion of all exchanges with iCloud, despite the fact that all the threads have been completed. I see problems in main thread.

Comment: All CloudKit opperations will be executed on a background queue. If you notice a delay in your main queue, then it must be some of your other code that is holding things up. Try eliminating parts of your code until the delay is gone.

Comment: I agree with Edwin's comment. I have seen no slowdown in my main thread.

Comment: I checked my code. All sync operations to this moment have been completed.

Comment: I upon receipt of data from iCloud create image from CKAsset, it may affect the performance of drawing them in a UIImageView?

Comment: when the CKRecord is received the asset is stored as a file on the device. You can use it's url to populate the UIImageView. The performance is than as fast as any other file that you would show.